# MonoMac/Cocoa fullscreen application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fullscreen, monomac

I'm trying to fullscreen a MonoMac/Cocoa application, by using EnterFullScreenModeWithOptions on the ContentView of a NSWindow. The following works great:

```
Window.ContentView.EnterFullscreenModeWithOptions(NSScreen.MainScreen, new NSDictionary());
```

However, I have some specific changes I want to make in the options dictionary, so I'm trying to create a NSDictionary with those changes:

```
var keys = new NSObject [] {
    NSView.NSFullScreenModeWindowLevel
};

var values = new NSObject [] {
    NSObject.FromObject(NSWindowLevel.Normal)
};

var dict = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(values, keys);
```

This simply gives a black screen, instead of the content in the view. The result is the same with the following Objective-C:

```
NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary
                         dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCGNormalWindowLevel],
                         NSFullScreenModeWindowLevel, nil];

[test.contentView enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen]
                   withOptions:options];
```

My overall goal is to try to allow launching external applications, while my application continues in fullscreen in the background, and without the dock or menubar appearing. Would it be possible following this path?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to control monomac full screen windows?

Comment: Fullscreen was possible and quite straightforward. Fullscreen with overlaying windows was without the task-bar was not.